# colorbutton plugin for CKEditor and figcaption

Tags: html, ckeditor

I use CKEditor (4.5.7) in one of my projects with several plugins. One of these is [colorbutton](http://ckeditor.com/addon/colorbutton). Its menus become dimmed if I try to change the color of some text inside the legend of some `figure` which corresponds to being inside a `figcaption`. Editing the source and creating a `span` there defining the color works but CKEditor will remove it on further editing.

Is this a feature or a bug? According to the HTML 5 spec it seems that flow content is valid inside `figcaption` and `span` is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm… Working for me: https://jsfiddle.net/Comandeer/e143dbfq/

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    extraAllowedContent: 'figure figcaption'
} );
```

By default, CKEditor removes `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` elements, so I allow them by using [the `extraAllowedContent` config option](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraAllowedContent). With that super simple configuration, applying color inside `figcaption` works as intended.

However the situation is different if you use [Enhanced Image plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/image2). In that case, using colors in captions is intentionally forbidden.

Comment: You are right @comandeer . I do use the [Enhanced Image plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/image2) and I do not seem to need to allow figcaption. Why is it forbidden to add colors to figcaption in this case?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't precise enough saying that it is forbidden. I meant that it's a default setting. Probably the `<span>` with styles is disallowed by default because it's unsemantic and could cause some accessibility issues (e.g. with contrast). However it's easy to change that default behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/Comandeer/qevtknoj/1/